# A class instance initializing with previously initialized attributes

Tags: python

I have a slight complication with my code. I want the pirate attribute to take the value True if the other two attributes are higher than some number when summed up and multiplied by some factor.

For instance, maybe I want the pirate attribute to be True only if social*0.6 + fixed is greater than 5, and false otherwise.

```
import random

class consumer(object):
"""Initialize consumers"""
    def __init__(self, fixed, social,pirate):
        self.social = social
        self.fixed = fixed
        self.pirate = pirate

"""Create an array of people"""
for x in range(1,people):
    consumerlist.append(consumer(random.uniform(0,10),random.uniform(0,10),True))
    pass
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but it is as easy as writing: `self.pirate = 0.6*social + fixed > 5` and removing the `pirate` argument from `__init__`

Comment: Note it is good practice to use an initial capital for class names, i.e. *Consumer* instead of *consumer*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In response to Moses answer: Using a calculated property is safer than calculating the pirate value at initialization only. When decorating a method with the @property attribute, it acts as a property (you don't have to use brackets as is the case for methods), which is always up to date when the social member is changed afterwards.

```
class Consumer(object):

    def __init__(self, fixed, social):
        self.fixed = fixed
        self.social = social

    @property
    def pirate(self):
        return self.social * 0.6 + self.fixed > 5

consumer1 = Consumer(1, 12)
print("Value of pirate attribute: " + str(consumer1.pirate))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the random values for `fixed` and `social` and then use them for the comparison that generates `pirate`:

```
for x in range(1,people):
     fixed = random.uniform(0,10)
     social = random.uniform(0,10)
     pirate = (social * 0.6 + fixed) > 5 # boolean
     consumerlist.append(consumer(fixed, social, pirate))
```

---

That pass in your for is redundant

Comment: This solution also works. How you implement the solution depends on the rest of your code. If you don't need the `pirate` argument in `__init__` somewhere else, I would remove it and handle the logic for setting `self.pirate` in `__init__` itself.